# Convert a blender into a dimmer lamp

Tags: repair, appliances

I was sitting around and suddenly wanted to convert my old blender into a lamp. The control panel would act as a dimmer switch. (And maybe the pulse button would be a big hit at raves.)

Can I just remove the motor and sub in a lightbulb socket?

For purposes of this lamp, I would prefer not to burn down my house, cause fuses to blow up in my neighborhood, destroy the power grid, etc.

I'm total n00b when it comes to circuitry, though I have soldered replacement parts onto PCB boards with success. Sorry if I'm not providing enough information or my question is just...wrong.  :)

Comment: Not actually an answer to your question, but: Don't do this. Even the tiniest mistake might in fact burn your house down. You should instead take out everything from the blender and replace it with a low-voltage LED lamp (with an external power supply). Way safer and way easier to implement.

Comment: `I was sitting around and suddenly wanted to convert my old blender into a lamp.` .... don't you just hate when that happens? .... lol .... +1 for making me laugh .... seriously though, i think that is how a lot of inventions were conceived

Comment: you should be able to replace the motor with a lightbulb .... whether it would dim in response to button pushes depends on the circuitry inside the blender ..... just be very careful .... unplug blender, swap motor, plug in blender ..... use a plastic object to press the buttons ....  always assume that something went wrong and measure the voltage between a ground reference and the blender before you touch the blender with your bare hands

Comment: @jsotola Cheers! They say necessity is the mother of invention, but so is boredom I guess. Do I have to measure the resistance of the motor and add/remove enough resistors to the circuit to keep it the same when I sub in a lightbulb? I imagine a lightbulb will have less resistance than a motor.

Comment: i think that a 30W lightbulb would have a higher impedance (resistance to ac current)

Comment: You'll need to figure out what kind of motor you have.  Motors are inductive, so you can't rely on resistance to predict their drive voltage.  If you're going to go ahead with this, take it apart as much as you can without damaging it and also see if you can find and learn anything from repair documents.  To take it apart safely you should make sure you understand basic electrical safety and capacitors at the very least.  Make sure with a voltmeter that you're not going to get a surprise zap.

Comment: It's unlikley your motor isn't a universal one, but in the off-chance it's a true DC motor and you replace it with a bulb, unscrewing the bulb while lit would be... interesting.

Answer (score 0):

you can't just swap the motor for the a lamp. because the speed control probably used a multi-wire motor (with a different wire for each speed)

you could fit several lamps and then have the buttons select a lamp. or you could possibly wire the push buttons in as the replacement for the potentometer in a regular triac lamp dimmer

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj5QAv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

but the heat from the lamps might be a problem, unless you use dimmable energy efficuient lamps. lit might be easier to go low voltage from the start and install LED lamps.

there's probably room where the motor was to put a LED power supply
and use rund the switched to the brighness input of the power supply.